# Delete a file if multiple conditions are met

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, text-processing

### What I need

I have an existing script that pulls port information for domains and stores it into a text file called `portscan.txt`. Example:

`portscan.txt` file:

```
somedomain.com:80
somedomain.com:443
```

I want to delete the information only if certain conditions are met. These conditions include:

- The file with the domains should have 2 or less lines
- The ports should only be 80 or 443 (i.e., I don't want to delete the file if 8080, 8443, or any other port exists in the file).

**Note:** So basically, the example file provided above **should** be deleted, but I do not want to delete the file if there are 2 lines, but the ports are 8080 or 8443 (or any other port for that matter)
Example like so:

```
somedomain.com:8443
somedomain.com:443
```

This should **not** be deleted.

### What I tried

I attempted scripting this out and here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(cat portscan.txt | wc -l)
ports=$(cat portscan.txt | grep -Pv '(^|[^0-9])(80|443)($|[^0-9])')


if [[ $lines < 3 ]] && [[ $ports != 80 ]]; then
    if [[ $ports != 443 ]]; then
        echo "I need to delete this"
    fi
else
    echo "I will NOT delete this..."
fi
```

This is the second rendering of the script, I attempted nested **if** statements because I was unable to do a condition like this:

**IF** portscan.txt is less than two lines **AND** the ports are **NOT** 80 **OR** 443

I also attempted this in a much simpler manner like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(cat portscan.txt | wc -l)
ports=$(cat portscan.txt | grep -Pv '(^|[^0-9])(80|443)($|[^0-9])')


if [[ $lines < 3 ]] && (( $ports != 80||443 )); then
    echo "I need to delete this"
else
    echo "I will NOT delete this..."
fi
```

I have tried the `((` because I read that this is better to be used with arithmetic functions -- which is what I thought I needed, but I'm not as bash savvy with conditional arguments when it should be like: "This **and** that **or** that".

Hopefully this makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```bsh
checkfile() {
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            FS = ":"
            status = 1
            ports[80] = 1
            ports[443] = 1
        }
        NR == 3 || !($2 in ports) {status = 0; exit}
        END {exit status}
    ' "$1"
}

file=portscan.txt
checkfile "$file" || echo rm -- "$file"
```

That awk command will exit with status 0 if the file has a 3rd line, or if it sees a "non-standard" port.

If the function returns non-zero (the file has <= 2 lines and only "standard" ports), then the rm command is printed.

Remove `echo` if the results look right.

---

Alternately:

```bsh
checkfile() {
    # if more than 2 lines, keep the file
    (( $(wc -l < "$1") > 2 )) && return 0

    # if a "non-standard" port exists, keep the file
    grep -qv -e ':80$' -e ':443$' "$1" && return 0

    # delete the file
    return 1
}
```

or, more tersely

```bsh
checkfile() {
    (( $(wc -l < "$1") > 2 )) || grep -qv -e ':80$' -e ':443$' "$1"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, try this

```bsh
[~/my_learning/lint]$ cat file.txt
somedomain.com:80
somedomain.com:443
[~/my_learning/lint]$ cat file_dont_delete.txt
somedomain.com:8443
somedomain.com:443

[~/my_learning/lint]$ for file in file.txt file_dont_delete.txt
do
num_of_lines=$(wc -l $file| xargs | awk '{print $1}')
port_scan=$(awk -F':' '{ if (($2 == "443") || ($2 == "80")) print "matched" }' $file | wc -l | xargs)
if [ $num_of_lines -le 2 ] && [ $num_of_lines -eq $port_scan ] ; then
echo "$file can be deleted"
else
echo "$file can't be deleted"
fi
done

# Output
file.txt can be deleted
file_dont_delete.txt can't be deleted
```

I follow the below conditions

- number of lines 2 or less than or 2.
- and for each line, I used awk to extract field 2 which is a port and check if it is either 80 or 443, and on any, I am printing `matching`.
- Then I am counting how many matching occurred.
- As per your description, even a single port that is not from 80 or 443 is presented, then I shouldn't delete the file.

Thank you for giving me this opportunity of writing the shell code.

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash solution, wrapped in a function and easy to read:

```
#!/bin/bash

possiblyDeleteFile() {
    local count=0
    local rLine port
    local otherPort=false
    while IFS= read -r -d'' rLine; do
        port="${rLine#*:}"
        ((count++))
        if [ "$port" != 80 ] && [ "$port" != 443 ]; then
            otherPort=true
        fi
    done < "$1"
    if [ $count -le 2 ] && ! $otherPort; then
        echo "Deleting file $1"
        rm -- "$1"
    fi
}

possiblyDeleteFile "$1"
```

Comment: I may be missing something, I don't see how this handles the "2 or less" rule - if there are 3 lines that all have port 80, `count` won't be incremented, so the file won't be deleted.

Comment: @minnmass Thank you, I did not get the question right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on mapfile:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

mapfile -tn3 a < $1
[[ ${#a[@]} -lt 3 ]] && { \
[[ ${#a[@]} -gt 0 && ${a[@]/%:@(80|443)} =~ :[0-9]+ ]] || echo rm -v -- $1; }
```

Answer (score -2):

To do numeric comparisons in bash you need to use `-gt`, `-lt`, etc. The `<` symbol is for stdin redirection.

You can either enclose the line number comparison in (( )) like you did for the port, or use `-lt` See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: `<` is stdin redirection inside *single* test brackets `[ ... ]`; inside `[[ ... ]]` as used by the OP it's a lexicographical comparison operator. See for example [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs)